# Drive a 50-Ohm load from a logic gate

Tags: logic-gates, impedance-matching, instrumentation

I have a device that I'm trying to send a trigger too, it has a 50\$\Omega\$ termination and suggests a pulse between 2-5 volts, ~1\$\mu\$s width. The way things are set up, the trigger needs to come from an AND gate (part # [MC74F08N](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/311/MC74F08N-pdf.php)); however, the IC is expecting to drive a high-Z load. My thoughts to accomplish this would be to set up a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIfM2D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I was wondering if this is the right approach, or if there is a better way to go about it?

If it is, would [this inverter](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hc14.pdf) be suitable?

**Edit 1**

Reflections aside, my understanding of impedance matching with a detector is based on a simple voltage divider.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcheT7.png)</sup>

If the source is expecting to drive a high-z load (\$R_{\rm load} >> R_{\rm src}\$) then it would need to generate a 5V signal. However, if (\$R_{\rm load} \approx R_{\rm src}\$), then the source would need to generate something closer to 10V. My understanding is that a typical logic gate can't sync the necessary current to do this, and is, therefore, not suitable for driving a \$50\Omega\$ load. Would a MOSFET be a reasonable solution to this? To mitigate reflections, do I need to match the resistor values of the receiver and the load on the FET (i.e. does the 1k\$\Omega\$ resistor need to be a \$50\Omega\$ resistor in the first figure?)

**Edit 2**

Initially, I incorrectly stated that my receiver was expecting a TTL pulse. The device suggests approximately a +5V pulse, triggering threshold is ~1V.

Comment: Closely related: [Turn TTL output of logic IC into output capable of driving 50 ohm devices](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122830) But I'm not voting to close as duplicate because the answers there can still be improved.

Comment: All CMOS 74HC drivers at 5V are approximately RdsOn = 50 Ohms . You can verify this with a 50 Ohm load and scope it read specs for Vol/Iol and (Vcc-Voh)/Ioh.  This is more balanced than 74F' series. The value is dependent on Vcc (inversely and has a loose tolerance but close enough for triggering purposes.  More important..  What are your trigger voltage levels ?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 All trigger voltage levels are 5V TTL

Comment: All TTL family (and CMOS 74HCT use a trigger level of 1.4V or 2 diode drops +/-0.1V

Comment: If you insist on using the 74F08 , simply add a pullup of 100 ~500 Ohms to +5V... V OH Output HIGH Voltage
54, 74 2.5 V I OH = –1.0 mA V CC = 4.50 V >>2V/1mA=2kOhm
74 2.7 V I OH = –1.0 mA V CC = 4.75 V
V OL Output LOW Voltage 0.5 V I OL = 20 mA V CC = MIN  >>>0.5V/20mA=25 ohm

Comment: So you see the 74F has a 25 Ohm "0" impedance and 2k "1" impedance  which is fine for triggering unless you have other constraints , like skew time.. with a 50 ohm load, the "1" becomes  attenuated so a 100 Ohm pullup gives greater immunity on the "1' and lower immunity of the "0" but if the input is TTL impedance then this is balanced for noise immunity

Comment: So understand the actual input requirements exactly. if TTL threshold AND 50 Ohms this is not the same as any TTL input

Comment: Since most TTL has a fanout of 10 you can compute input impedance of TTL to be approx 10x of output impedance (asymmetric) and give the same power margin to noise immunity away from Vth=1.4V. this is how all discrete logic families are designed. for balanced power noise immunity. (albeit TTL has inbalanced Z and V)

Comment: I will have to digest the details of your comments to better understand the difference, but it looks like I was incorrect in saying that it was a TTL pulse.

Comment: "suggests a pulse between 2-5 volts... triggering threshold is ~1V." TTL is >2.0V high and <0.8V low. I think we can assume that TTL voltage levels would be OK. Driver will need to deliver at least 40mA @ 2V with 50 Ohm output impedance (both sourcing and sinking).